# CURDATE() NOT IN (select room where CURDATE() between CheckIn and CheckOut)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

How can I make work my query?

I want to get the data from my SQL where the date today is not listed.

Here is my query:

```
String sql = "select Room, Name, Age, EmailAddress, Phone, Nationality, CheckIn, CheckOut from customer where CURDATE() NOT IN (SELECT Room FROM customer WHERE CURDATE() between CheckIn and Checkout)";
```

[image: Data Structure]

[image]

Comment: This looks like MySQL, so I added appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `NOT BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT Room, Name, Age, EmailAddress, Phone, Nationality, CheckIn, CheckOut
FROM customer
WHERE CURDATE() NOT BETWEEN CheckIn AND Checkout
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where CURDATE() NOT IN (SELECT c2.Room
                        FROM customer c2
                        WHERE CURDATE() between c2.CheckIn and c2.Checkout
                       );
```

Without knowing your data structure or exactly what you want the query to do, it is really hard to say what the query should be.

However, it would be a really, really, really unusual data model where a column called `Room` was comparable to `curdate()`.  I assume that is at least part of your problem.

If you want to get rooms that are not booked today, then start with the `rooms` table (I assume you have one!):

```
select r.*
from rooms r
where not exists (select 1
                  from bookings b -- a more natural name for a table with bookings
                  where curdate() between b.CheckIn and b.CheckOut
                 );
```